# Angular2: Get incoming request header

Tags: angular, http-headers

I can find heaps of examples of adding headers in Angular2, but they are all for situations when you are creating a request to get some data. I'm trying to do the reverse, get the incoming request header when someone visits my site.

In asp.net I would do something like

```
        var re = Request;
        var headers = re.Headers;
```

Never used Angular v1, but it looks like it had interceptors for this?

Edit: Clarification

Lets say you visit my site www.123.com and add a header value (X-CustomValue: hello) , how can I get the value of X-CustomValue into my angular2 code?

Comment: There's no such thing as _in-coming_ request headers in Angular. Angular isn't a server. Do yo mean you want to get the _response_ headers?

Comment: Angular can't see that. You would need to either render that vaue into Angular when the Angular page is served, or you need to store that value on the server, and when Angular is loaded, make an XHR request for that value.